# How to handle returned different http status codes separately in Fetch Api?

Tags: javascript, angular, httprequest, fetch-api

I am sending a request to backend but backend can return different status codes as below:

```
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> loginUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User userObj;
            if (isNull(userDto.getEmail()) || isNull(userDto.getPassword())) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    userObj = userService.getUserByEmailAndPassword(userDto);
                    if (isNull(userObj)) {
                        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    }
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(modelMapper.map(userObj, UserDto.class));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            }
    }
```

And previous version of my fetch method call is:

```
async loginUser() {
  let response = await this._service.loginUser(this.user)
  .then(response => {return response.json()})
  .then(response => {
    if (response.error) {
      this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent);
  } else {
    this._router.navigate(['/mainpage'], {queryParams: {userId: response.userId}})
  }
  })
  .catch(error => {alert("Something went wrong")});
 }
```

What I want to do es handling the response different according the status code of the response something like:

```
async loginUser() {
      let response = await this._service.loginUser(this.user)
      .then(response => {return response.json()}).
then if status code is 401 (do this)
then if status code is 500 (do this)
.
.
etc
```

How can i handle it ?

Comment: The logic for handling the response code probably needs to be done in the first `then()`.  The status code should exist some where on that `response` parameter

Comment: are you getting the status code from API ?

Comment: Though you may have to double check.  Since the endpoint is return the status code as 401 and 500, those are not success status codes, so the fail callback is probably being executed.  Which would be a secondary callback to the first `then()`

Comment: @micronyks yes i am getting the status codes from the backend api

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can implement something as below,

```
export enum STATUSCODE{

     NOTFOUND= 401,
     ERROR = 500,
     ...
}
    
async loginUser() {
      let response = await this._service.loginUser(this.user)
      .then(response => {return response.json()})
      .then(response => {
     
        ...
        ...

        switch (response.status)) {
           case STATUSCODE.NOTFOUND: // do something here
                     break;
           case STATUSCODE.ERROR: // do something here
                     break;
        }
        
        ...
        ...
      })
      .catch(error => {alert("Something went wrong")});
}
```

**Side Note**: You can handle all http status codes at central place using **[HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)**

Comment: `statusCode` is not a valid property of `response`. You probably mean `status`

Comment: In the switch statement, `response` no longer refers to the HTTP Response, it refers to the parsed JSON body.

Answer (score 1):

The `response` object has a property [status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status) which is the http status code returned by the server.

Comment: the problem is, no matter what is error code is, the fetch api is going to catch() block if the response is not 200. And i cannot reach the status from the "error" variable

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn that's not correct. From the mdn page  `The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.`

Answer (score 0):

You can see HTTP-status in the response properties.

```
status – HTTP status code, e.g. 200.
ok – boolean, true if the HTTP status code is 200-299.
```

Knowing that you can access response.status in your if statement and compare it.

Comment: the problem is, no matter what is error code is, the fetch api is going to catch() block if the response is not 200. And i cannot reach the status from the "error" variable

Comment: Ah yes, I can see that. Maybe you can reach the error variable in the catch() callback function and do your logic in there. Dunno if that is the right way to do it tho...